# PHP ZIP Function Returning a corrupted file

Tags: php, archive, zip

I have create a script to backup my server files as well as the database and upload them to a remote server .. When running the script, it works like a charm and as expected. I get a SQL file, and a ZIP file.

My problem is with the ZIP file. When I downloaded the file to my PC, I wasn't able to open it via 7-ZIP. Below is the code I use to generate the ZIP File:

```
// Get real path for our folder
$rootPath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
$archiveName = date("Ymd") . '-backup.zip';

// Initialize archive object
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open("./BACKUP/" . $archiveName, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

// Create recursive directory iterator
/** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($files as $name => $file)
{
    // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
    if (!$file->isDir())
    {
        // Get real and relative path for current file
        $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
        $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

        // Add current file to archive
        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
    }
}
// Zip archive will be created only after closing object
$zip->close();
while(!file_exists("./BACKUP/" . $archiveName)) {}
```

The file is stored on a remote server hosted by X10hosting (in case this helps)

Comment: Try opening the file in a text editor and see if there is any extra unexpected output such as php error messages.

Comment: Can you check the returned value of `$zip->addFile`? It should return `false` if something went wrong

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: File is Gibberish for me .. no PHP error in it. Also, the files that are compressed are there by names.

Comment: @OfirBaruch: It is returning "1" .. So, no issue there I guess

Comment: Can you check if the returned value for `$zip->close()` is `1` as well?
And consider adding the following condition: `if(file_exists($filePath)) { add to zip; }else{ echo 'error with '.$file_path. '\n'; }`

Comment: returning 1 as well ..

Comment: I tried winzip as well, it's giving me an error: "`Error: unable to seek to beginning of central directory.`" .. 7-zip gives: "`Can not open file as archive`"

Comment: And if you're adding the `file_exists` condition - all the files really exist?
Maybe you have some files with unicode names?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79804/discussion-between-sikas-and-ofir-baruch).